# Populating second picker corresponding to the value selected in first picker view on same view

Tags: ios, xcode, uipickerview

I want to use two picker views in same view where first picker view is of category and when a category is selected, its corresponding values are added to second picker view. How can I make it possible? Values are taken from JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get value selected in first picker view like this

```
NSInteger row;
NSArray *firstPickerViewDataArray;
UIPickerView *firstPickerView;
NSString *selectedValue;

row = [firstPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
selectedValue  = [firstPickerViewDataArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

Get the data from server or wherever you want and store that into another array like

```
NSArray * secondPickerViewDataArray;
```

After that you can use below method to show values

```
    - (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
        if (pickerView == secondPickerView){
          // Do whatever you want based on selected value in first PickerView
            return secondPickerViewDataArray[row];
            }else{
   //stuff for first pickerView
         }
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is fairly simple. You must be populating your second picker view from an array.

Make your view controller the delegate and data source for both the picker views.

Then when the 'func pickerView(UIPickerView, didSelectRow: Int, inComponent: Int)' delegate method is called when you select an item in the first picker view, update the data array for the second picker view and call reloadAllComponents on it

Here is some code

```
func pickerView(UIPickerView, didSelectRow: Int, inComponent: Int)
{
    if (pickerView == self.firstPicker)
    {
        //calculate your data array for the second picker here
        self.secondPickerView.reloadAllComponents()
    }
}
```

Comment: yes second view is being populated with array, issue is, if i select an object at index 1 in first picker view then the data array in second picker is retrieved from that object only.